# php curl not getting same response as fiddler

Tags: php, curl, fiddler

This is my PHP code :

```
$source = $_POST['source'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];

$data = array(
    'lccp_src_stncode_dis' => $source,
    'lccp_dstn_stncode' => $destination,
    'lccp_classopt' => $class,
    'lccp_day' => $day,
    'lccp_month' => $month
);

# Create a connection
$url = 'data as per raw req ';
$ch = curl_init($url);

echo $ch." <br>";

# Form data string
$postString = http_build_query($data);

echo $postString;
$header = array (   
            'Host' => 'data as per raw req '
            'Connection'=> 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length'=> '180',
            'Cache-Control'=> 'max-age=0',
            'Accept'=> 'text/html',
            'Origin'=> 'data as per raw req ',
            'User-Agent' => '',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Referer': 'data as per raw req '
            'Accept-Encoding'=> '',
            'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8'

    );

# Setting options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
//# Get the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

#print response
echo "
$response
";
```

receiving form data from:

```
<html>
    <form method="post" action="poster.php">
        <table>
            <tr><td>source:</td><td><input type="text" name="source"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>destination:</td><td><input type="text" name="destination"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>day:</td><td><input type="text" name="day"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>month:</td><td><input type="text" name="month"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>class:</td><td><input type="text" name="class"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr>
        </table>
</form>
</html>
```

this is the raw request

```
POST http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_srcdest_cgi_date.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: www.indianrail.gov.in
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 91
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html
Origin: **<---modified since I can't post more than 2 links
User-Agent: 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: ** <---modified since I can't post more than 2 links
Accept-Encoding: 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
lccp_src_stncode_dis=ndls&lccp_dstn_stncode=HYB&lccp_classopt=SL&lccp_day=26&lccp_month=6
```

Fiddler is giving the appropriate response from the cgi, whereas the php script just shows the html container, I've been stuck for over an hour ! Please help !
**EDIT**: output from verbose :

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x2cab910
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 3 (0x2cab910) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.indianrail.gov.in port 80 (#3)
*   Trying 203.176.113.78...
* Connected to www.indianrail.gov.in (203.176.113.78) port 80 (#3)
> POST /cgi_bin/inet_srcdest_cgi_date.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: www.indianrail.gov.in
Accept: */*
http://www.indianrail.gov.in
http://www.indianrail.gov.in/know_Station_Code.html
Content-Length: 89
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
* upload completely sent off: 89 out of 89 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 05:38:17 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Closing connection 3
```

^Off topic: Why did it just let me post links this time, it should have been recognized as links ?

Also, I would compare sessions in fiddler, but fiddler shows the request to my own app on local host, not from my app to the indian railways site.
screenshot :
*NEVERMIND, NOT ENOUGH REP*

EDIT:
I'll be happy if someone can show me how to make this request with http_request2 as well 
 I've posted the exact raw request that gives me the required output with fiddler in the comments, so no, I'm not missing any authentication and cookie headers and the like

Comment: actual raw request :POST http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_srcdest_cgi_date.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: www.indianrail.gov.in
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 91
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html
Origin: http://www.indianrail.gov.in
User-Agent: 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.indianrail.gov.in/know_Station_Code.html
Accept-Encoding: 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

lccp_src_stncode_dis=ndls&lccp_dstn_stncode=HYB&lccp_classopt=SL&lccp_day=26&lccp_month=6

Comment: Are you sure you recreated the ENTIRE http request with curl? I don't see any Cookie headers in there, for instance.

Comment: you can enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE for php-curl to see similar output to curl -v to make debugging easier

Comment: not needed, the exact raw request I've posted as comment gives the required output in fiddler. will post the verbose output

Comment: You can use Fiddler's `Compare Sessions` feature to compare the CURL request to the Fiddler request and see how exactly they differ.

Comment: Anyway, you guys can go ahead and ctr-c ctr-v the raw request in my comment and fiddler and see the output for yourselves.

Comment: ^ since that'll work, you know that I'm not missing any cookie headers and the like.

Comment: Is your PHP code correct? You're using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS twice for some reason?

Comment: oh, i commented one out, i found the problem,its in the header, you don't set it as an associative array, should I delete the question or answer it myself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header is not to be entered as an associative array, this is wrong :

```
$header = array (   
            'Host' => 'data as per raw req '
            'Connection'=> 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length'=> '180',
            'Cache-Control'=> 'max-age=0',
            'Accept'=> 'text/html',
            'Origin'=> 'data as per raw req ',
            'User-Agent' => '',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Referer': 'data as per raw req '
            'Accept-Encoding'=> '',
            'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
             );
```

correct method :

```
$header = array (   
            'Host:*data as per raw req* '
            'Connection:keep-alive',
            'Content-Length:180',
            'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
            'Accept:text/html',
            'Origin:*data as per raw req* ',
            'User-Agent:',
            'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Referer:*data as per raw req* '
            'Accept-Encoding:',
            'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8'
             );
```

even the data entered in the associative array I've used is formatted to a url encoded post string, apparently everything pretty much has to be entered as it is in a raw http request. cURL doesn't really do any formatting.